# Verify signature in C++

Tags: c++, openssl

I have a function that verifies signature in C++ using Openssl functions.
the verify does not work.

```
int verify(char *msg, int msg_len, char *signature, int signature_len, char *cert_str, int cert_len) {

X509* cert = d2i_X509(NULL, &cert_str, cert_len);

EVP_PKEY* key = X509_get_pubkey(cert);

EVP_MD_CTX* ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
EVP_MD_CTX_init(ctx);

X509_ALGOR *palg = NULL;
ASN1_OBJECT *paobj = NULL;
X509_get0_signature(NULL, &palg, cert);
TRACE_ASSERT(T_PLUGIN, palg);
X509_ALGOR_get0(&paobj, NULL, NULL, palg);
int alg = OBJ_obj2nid(paobj);

const EVP_MD* md = EVP_get_digestbynid(alg);

EVP_VerifyInit_ex(ctx, md, NULL);
EVP_VerifyUpdate(ctx, msg, msg_len);

return EVP_VerifyFinal(ctx, signature, signature_len, key) == 1);
```

for some unknown reason the verify return 0 on things that should pass verification.
the msg, signature and cert_str are bytearrays converted to char*.
the conversions work fine as far as I've checked.
Am I missing anything, did something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you check with [this](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.1/crypto/ERR_get_error.html) function what goes wrong?

Comment: i get this error: 185057381

Comment: Googleing around you can find that means "cert already in hash table", can you proceed debugging with this information?

Comment: hi, after a small trial and error i have inserted X509_free(cert) before the verify and now the error is 67702888 - bad signature.
i know the signature is good, any idea why it will return such thing?
thanks very much!

Comment: Also see [EVP Signing and Verifying](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Signing_and_Verifying) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: i've tried to do the same as there but it didn't work either

Comment: does it matter that the certificate is RSA or something else?